# Windows App Cert Kit (WACK) Log Folder?

Tags: windows-10-universal

Where is the current location of the log/dump files from using WACK? Does WACK by default generated them or do you have to manually run WACK to generate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you're using Visual Studio, you can run the **Windows App Certification Kit** when you create your app package. See [Packaging UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) to learn how. In this case, the **Windows App Certification Kit** creates an HTML along with XML reports and saves it in the path:

C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/AppCertKit/

The HTML file name should be **ValidationResult.htm**.

But if you don't want validate your Windows app when you package your app, you can validate your app later by launching the Windows App Certification Kit directly. See [Validate your Windows app using the Windows App Certification Kit interactively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit#validate-your-windows-app-using-the-windows-app-certification-kit-interactively) to get the steps. When you use this way, you need to select the path to the folder where you want to save the test report(the XML file) at the prompt after the test, but the **ValidationResult.htm** file is still in the path: C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/AppCertKit/